# Internet Explorer and Windows Phone not recognizing UTF-8 on a specific host

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-phone

I have a web page with the following character encoding config:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
    ...
```

This works perfectly on other browsers, but both IE and Windows phone fail to show scandic characters correctly. This seems to be partly related to my hosting service because when I test the same code on another host I have access to, encoding works as expected.

I'm curious what the problem might be and if there is anything I could do from my side without contacting my web hotel service provider?

Comment: The `<meta>` declaration *inside* the file is possibly the least important detail. Assuming data is actually UTF-8 (just saying so is not enough) you need to send a proper `Content-Type` HTTP header. Is it dynamically generated HTML or static HTML? What web server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered:

[UTF 8 A working B not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430212/utf-8-works-on-hosting-a-but-not-on-hosting-b-what-could-be-causing-it)

but add maybe

`AddDefaultCharSet utf-8 on` .htaccess

Here is also one way [Solving Character problems](https://jalbum.net/help/en/Solving_character_encoding_problems) Try it with charset=ISO-8859-1